# I am doing a homework and this code need to print an error message when a negative number is inputted

Tags: python

This program haves to print the avg, highest, lowest and total of the inputs but I am having problems how to make the code print an error message when the input is a negative number.
For some reason I don't find the way I don't know if am being too dumb or what

```
Days = []
day1 = int(input("Enter day 1 rainfall: "))
day2 = int(input("Enter day 2 rainfall: "))
day3 = int(input("Enter day 3 rainfall: "))
day4 = int(input("Enter day 4 rainfall: "))
day5 = int(input("Enter day 5 rainfall: "))
day6 = int(input("Enter day 6 rainfall: "))
day7 = int(input("Enter day 7 rainfall: "))
day8 = int(input("Enter day 8 rainfall: "))
day9 = int(input("Enter day 9 rainfall: "))
day10=int(input("Enter day 10 rainfall: "))

Days.extend((day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7, day8, day9, day10 ))

def lowest():
    print('The minimum rainfall is', min(Days))
lowest()

def highest():
    print('The most rainfall is', max(Days))
highest()

def total():
    print('The total rainfall is', sum(Days))
total()

def average():
    print('The average rainfall is', float(sum(Days))/len(Days))
average()
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming You need 10  inputs, if  user enter wrong input, you want to retake that input from user.

```py
Days = []
while True:
   day = int(input(f"Enter day {len(Days)+1} rainfall: "))
   if day < 0:
      print("Invalid Input")
      continue
   Days.append(day)
   if len(Days) == 10:
       break
      
def lowest():
    print('The minimum rainfall is', min(Days))


def highest():
    print('The most rainfall is', max(Days))

def total():
    print('The total rainfall is', sum(Days))

def average():
    print('The average rainfall is', float(sum(Days))/len(Days))

lowest()
highest()
total()
average()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put your statements asking for user input in a loop, and in the loop you can check if the number is negative, as follows:

```
Days = []
for count in range(1, 11):
    day = int(input("Enter day " + count + " rainfall: "))
    if day < 0:
        print("Error")
        # You can handle the error here
    Days.append(day)

def lowest():
    print('The minimum rainfall is', min(Days))
lowest()

def highest():
    print('The most rainfall is', max(Days))
highest()

def total():
    print('The total rainfall is', sum(Days))
total()

def average():
    print('The average rainfall is', float(sum(Days))/len(Days))
average()
```